# what's the difference between grouby id and by level

Tags: pandas, group-by

What's the difference between groupby ID and by level?

Below code putput looks like the same:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [12345, 123.78],
    [12345, 556.87],
    [12345, 1638.09],
    [12345, 133.44],
    [56789, 44],
    [56789, 434.2],
    [56789, 24.44]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','Value'])
print(df)

g1 = df.groupby('ID')
g2 = df.set_index("ID").groupby(level=0)

print("g1")    
for name,df in g1:
    print(name)
    print(df)

print("g2")    
for name,df in g2:
    print(name)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
      ID    Value
0  12345   123.78
1  12345   556.87
2  12345  1638.09
3  12345   133.44
4  56789    44.00
5  56789   434.20
6  56789    24.44
g1
12345
      ID    Value
0  12345   123.78
1  12345   556.87
2  12345  1638.09
3  12345   133.44
56789
      ID   Value
4  56789   44.00
5  56789  434.20
6  56789   24.44
g2
12345
         Value
ID            
12345   123.78
12345   556.87
12345  1638.09
12345   133.44
56789
        Value
ID           
56789   44.00
56789  434.20
56789   24.44
```

Comment: Generally, pretty much nothing except for the `df` in the grouping: one has `ID` as index, the other has it as a column. Also `df.set_index("ID").groupby("ID")` would be identical to `.groupby(level=0)` as well.